# ajdt.pdebuild.scripts not set during AJDT headless PDE build

Tags: aspectj, pde, headless, ajdt

I have an eclipse rcp application being developed in eclipse 3.5. I am able to successfully execute pde headless build in ant (*from command shell outside eclipse*) via the following target entry:

```
<target name="compile">
    <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir="some-dir">
        <arg value="-application" />
        <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_${some-version}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
        <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
        <arg value="-propertyfile" />
        <arg value="${some-dir}/ant.properties" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement
                 location="${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${some-version}.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

But once AspectJ (AJDT) got involved, I modified the target above like so:

```
<target name="compile">
    <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir="${some-dir}">
        <arg value="-application" />
        <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />      
        **<arg value="${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.ajdt.pde.build_2.0.2.e35x-release-20101021-0900/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />**
        <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
        <arg value="-propertyfile" />
        <arg value="${some-dir}/ant.properties" />
        **<jvmarg value="-Dajdt.pdebuild.home=${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.ajdt.pde.build_2.0.2.e35x-release-20101021-0900" />**            
        <classpath>
            <pathelement
                          location="${eclipse.location}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${some-version}.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Unfortunately, I am now getting the following error:

c:\eclipse-3.5\plugins\org.eclipse.ajdt.pde.build_2.0.2.e35x-release-20101021-0900\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml:8: **Cannot find ${ajdt.pdebuild.scripts}**/productBuild/allElements.xml imported from c:\eclipse-3.5\plugins\org.eclipse.ajdt.pde.build_2.0.2.e35x-release-20101021-0900\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml

does anyone have any idea on how to set the ajdt.pdebuild.scripts value? thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post:

http://contraptionsforprogramming.blogspot.com/2010/03/ajdt-pde-builds-redux.html

You should not be using AJDT-PDE.  That is the old way of doing things and is no longer supported.  Instead, you should be making changes to your build.properties file:

```
# required
compilerAdapter=org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ant.AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter
sourceFileExtensions=*.java, *.aj

# optional
compilerArg=-aspectpath other.jar
```

Read the blog post for more details.

Comment: thank you for you response, Andrew. I have read through that very same article. unfortunately, the new approach you speak of applies to eclipse 3.6 and on. I am running 3.5 as specified in my initial post.

Comment: ... and since our currenlt release is locked into 3.5, I cannot upgrade to 3.6.

Comment: Don't confuse your target environment with your build environment.  Just because you need to target Eclipse, doesn't mean that you can't build using Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7.

Comment: But perhaps a more important question is...why are you still locked into 3.5?

Comment: Andrew, i am not going to get into discussion as to why we are locked into 3.5. we just are, and i cannot do anything about it. i am sure that 3.5 ajdt pde headless builds were performed performed before 3.6, and i simply would like to know how. specifically, why the aforementioned property is not set.

Comment: Sorry...I didn't mean to touch a sore spot.  :)  Before 3.6, there was a bit of black magic going on, and it didn't work in all situations, but as you mention in your other post, you need to add a "ajdt.pdebuild.scripts" property to your ant script.  If this doesn't work for you, let me know what the problem is.

Comment: no need to apologize. if there is a sore spot, it is the lack of info on eclipse side when it comes to such fundamental functionality. anyways, i added "ajdt.pdebuild.scripts" as a "jvmarg". that took care of the related error, but it now results in a different error:

plugins\org.eclipse.ajdt.pde.build_2.0.2.e35x-release-20101021-0900\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[java] Target "preBuild" does not exist in the project "Build a Product".

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you need to add a preBuild target to your customTargets.xml file:
    <target name="preBuild">
    </target>

Comment: preBuild target already exists in scripts/build.xml. the problem is that unlike standard pde, ajdt-pde's scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml does NOT import scripts/build.xml.
which leads me to my next question. a lot of standard pde examples state that **scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml** should be executed, while ajdt-pde examples state that **scripts/build.xml** should be executed. what is the correct way for each, but more importantly for the latter? thanks!

Comment: You are hitting on some of the problems with the old style ajdt-pde.  It was created specifically so that AJDT itself could be built.  It was essentially a fork of the original PDE, but with some aspectJ specific changes.  This turned out to be too hard to maintain and even harder to test (so we didn't test it, except to ensure that AJDT itself could continue to be built).  So when errors like this would come up and we wouldn't have a good basis for answering them.  That is why we moved to the new style of pde builds.  So, unfortunately, I can't answer this question.

Comment: Well...ok I might be able to answer this question.  Try editing some of the build scripts in ajdt-pde so that they more closely resemble what is in the real pde.  But, once again, I would like to stress that this would be much smoother if you were to simply upgrade your build eclipse to 3.6 or 3.7.

Comment: i did just that, and now ajdt-pde build runs fine, but only against my regular plugin projects. so since the question at hand has been resolved, i will create a new thread. thank you, Andrew, for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

there are several steps needed to wrangle ajdt-pde headless build to execute in eclipse 3.5:

1) add **ajdt.pdebuild.scripts** param with its respective value as a "jvmarg" to the above-shown "java" block.
2) in **.../scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml**, change **property name="allElementsFile" value="productBuild/allElements.xml"** to this **property name="allElementsFile" value="${ajdt.pdebuild.scripts}/productBuild/allElements.xml"**
3) in **.../scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml**, comment out **import file="${ajdt.pdebuild.scripts}/productBuild/allElements.xml"**
4) in **.../scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml**, paste the following import statement: **import file="${ajdt.pdebuild.scripts}/build.xml"**